# retrieve json is in wrong format in java

Tags: java, jackson

I want retrieve json from postgres sql and I will convert it to a plain string.
I want full json with json String.

```
DeviceProfile dp = device.getDp();
System.out.println("parameters Data:: "+dp.getParameters().toString());
JSONObject parameters = new ObjectMapper().readValue(dp.getParameters().toString(),JSONObject.class);
```

It will print following String which is wrong.

```
{Rs232=[{rs232unit=, parameterId=6, rs232ioindex=1.0, parametername=rs232}], Digital=[{reverse=true, dioindex=1.0, parameterId=1, parametername=Ignition}]}
```

I want proper json.

I am using jsckson api to parse data.

[See database Screen Short](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5gAG.png)

Comment: Are you sure `dp.getParameters().toString()` would return JSON?

Comment: it will return json which is stored in database. i had attached a screen short also.

Comment: Obviously, it doesn't. What makes you think it would? Is `DeviceProfile` one of your classes? I would start to look there.

Comment: Yes DeviceProfile is my Model Class.